# Parametrize the curve of intersection of 2 surfaces

Tags: calculus

I have to parametrize the curve of intersection of 2 surfaces.
The surfaces are:

$z=x^2+y^2$ and $2x-4y-z-1=0$

Could someone please show me how to do this step by step?
Thank you.

Comment: Do you understand what a parametrization of a set is?

Comment: I just don't understand how to do it when one of the equations is not independent of one variable

Comment: Do you understand that you need to find a function in which its domain is an interval and such that the image of the function is the set $\{(x,y,z)\in \Bbb R^3\colon z=x^2+y^2 \land 2x-4y-z-1=0\}$?

Comment: Yeah, I guess..

Answer (score 8):

Well, setting the common value of $z$ equal to itself, we get

$$x^2+y^2=2 x-4 y-1$$

or

$$x^2-2 x + y^2+4 y=-1 \implies (x-1)^2+(y+2)^2=4 $$

This is a circle of radius $2$ centered at $(1,-2)$.  A standard parametrization of this is

$$x=1+2 \cos{t}$$
$$y=-2+2 \sin{t}$$

Comment: Every point in the intersection verifies your rewritten equation. But it is not the case that every point that verifies your equation is in the intersection. Is that not a problem?

Comment: @JackM If you're right, it is a problem. Can you give a specific example?

Comment: Pick any point in the intersection, and it verifies your equation. Now change the value of $z$ to anything you like. Since your rewritten equation doesn't involve $z$, clearly the new point must still verify it.

Comment: @JackM: yeah, that's the thing... *you can't do that* because you have already specified particular values of $x$ and $y$ (i.e., those in this intersection).  So, no, you cannot just pick *any* value of $z$.

Comment: @RonGordon I suppose it depends what you do with the parameterization. I guess you're implicitly using $z(t) = x(t)^2 + y(t)^2$?

Comment: @JackM The parametrization Ron is suggesting is $\gamma (t)=(1+2\cos (t), -2+2\sin (t), (1+2\cos(t))^2+(-2+2\sin (t))^2)$, for all $t\in [0,2\pi]$.

Comment: @GitGud In your comment under the OP you stated that in this case a paramaterization would have to take values in $\Bbb R^3$, which is why I added $z(t)$.

Comment: @JackM Of course, I had forgotten about the original problem. I edited the comment above.

Answer (score 3):

Well, use the substitution $$z=2x-4y-1\tag{$\star$}$$ to get $$-1=x^2-2x+y^2+4y,$$ which gets you $$2^2=(x-1)^2+(y+2)^2$$ by completing the square twice. We can rewrite this as $$1=\left(\frac{x-1}2\right)^2+\left(\frac{y+2}2\right)^2.$$ Can you get the rest of the way from here? (**Hint**: Think about trigonometric identities.) Don't forget to "plug in" to $(\star)$ once you've parameterized $x,y$.