# Find the curve of intersection of the surfaces $x^2+y^2=z$ and $x+y+z=1$

Tags: calculus, geometry, multivariable-calculus

> Find the curve of intersection of the surfaces $x^2+y^2=z$ and $x+y+z=1$.

So if we substitute $z=1-x-y$ into the equation $x^2+y^2=z$ we get $x^2+y^2=1-x-y$ which can be written in the form $\left(x+\frac{1}{2}\right)^2+\left(y+\frac{1}{2}\right)^2=1$.

Is this the curve of intersection? Because it seems to me (by geometrical intuition) that the curve should be an ellipse. What is the logical flaw here. Help please!

Comment: Please see here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/442728/parametrize-the-curve-of-intersection-of-2-surfaces

Comment: I would say - the circle is projection of  the curve of intersection to plane z = 0.

Comment: The equation you have derived is a cylinder in three dimensions. But you need to bring in the condition on $z$ again too.

Comment: In my arithmetic $1+\frac14+\frac14=\frac32$.

Comment: @LutzL What does that mean in this problem's context...?

Comment: @MarkBennet What condition on $\;z\;$ to bring in *where* ?

Comment: @DonAntonio : That the last equation is slightly wrong but can be easily repaired. -- And any of the two original equations is a condition on $z$.

Comment: @LutzL Ah, that...yes, you're right. Thanks.

Comment: @DonAntonio Well solving for $x$ and $y$ from the equation for the circle does not constrain $z$, so you still need $z=1-x-y$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After the coments, a possible parametrization is

$$r(t)=\left(\,-\frac12+\sqrt\frac32\,\cos t\,,\,\,-\frac12+\sqrt\frac32\,\sin t\,,\,\,2-\sqrt\frac32(\cos t+\sin t)\,\right)\;,\;\;0\le t\le 2\pi$$

Observe that we have above a general vector of the form $\;(x,y,z)\;$ , where for the third coordinate we have either $\;z=x^2+y^2\;$ or $\;z=1-x-y\;$ .

Answer (score 3):

There is an error in your algebra

$$\left(x+\frac{1}{2}\right)^2+\left(y+\frac{1}{2}\right)^2=\frac32$$

so parametrically continue from here.

$$ x = \sqrt{\frac32} \cos t -\frac12\,,y =\sqrt{\frac32}  \sin t -\frac12 $$

Plug these into the second equation and find $z$ in terms of $t$.